# Customizing OpenSSH

Tags: c, ssh, openssh

I currently am assigned to investigate and somehow find a way to "customize" (make modifications re authentication, constants, messages, etc) OpenSSH and being the "web-based" guy that I am, I really don't know where to start. So comments are highly appreciated.

Questions:

1. I downloaded the latest snapshot from [here](http://www.mindrot.org/openssh_snap/), I believe this is the code I am supposed to "customize" right?
2. For confirmation: Can I "customize" these codes in Windows?
3. Is OpenSSH a "library" that I need to call externally from codes I'll be writing or the "program" itself that I need to edit?

Sorry for the noobish questions but I just need expert comments on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off all which kind of customization you wants ,please be clear.

```
1.I downloaded the latest snapshot from here, I believe this is the code I am supposed to "customize" right?
```

So latest code is here http://openbsd.org.ar/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-6.4p1.tar.gz

```
2.For confirmation: Can I "customize" these codes in Windows?
```

You can but compilation is easy in linux so please modify and compile your code in any linux machine, refer this link for compiling and configuring openSSH http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/openssh.html

```
3.Is OpenSSH a "library" that I need to call externally from codes I'll be writing or the "program" itself that I need to edit?
```

OpenSSH is not a library its a ssh server and client programs which runs on linux.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I appreciate it. The customizations I want are for example (make modifications re authentication, constants, messages, etc) which are code and not just config level.

Comment: So you can run sshd (SSH server ) in debug mode like sshd -d and you are able to see debug messages by connecting using ssh client